# LIGO flawed by the identical expansion of laser wavelength and arms in presence of a gravitational wave?

Tags: experimental-physics, gravitational-waves, interferometry, ligo

[LIGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO), Laser Interferometer Gravitational-Wave Observatory, is a large-scale physics experiment aiming to directly detect gravitational waves.
The device measures the phase shift laser beams.

If I understand this well, the measurement assumes that a suitable gravitational wave reduces and prolongs one of the tubes and the extension will take effect in the phase-shifting laser beams.

But I think if there's a gravitational wave that passes through it, it will affect everything, even the laser beam. This means that when the wave lengthens or shortens the tube, it also lengthens or shortens the wavelength of the laser beam.

In my opinion, therefore, this device does not work. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Here is the PRL https://dcc.ligo.org/public/0122/P150914/014/LIGO-P150914%3ADetection_of_GW150914.pdf

Comment: a video of the announcement  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_582rU6neLc

Comment: The speed of light remains constant. It fixes everything.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[LIGO has now observed gravitational waves](https://web.archive.org/web/20190503054526/https://www.nature.com/news/einstein-s-gravitational-waves-found-at-last-1.19361), so the theory for it working is clearly sound.

The light path itself is also affected by the gravitational wave. The Wikipedia article on [LIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO) says,

> Note that the effective length change and the resulting phase change are a subtle tidal effect that must be carefully computed because the light waves are affected by the gravitational wave just as much as the beams themselves.

Wikipedia then provides a link to [Chapter 27 of Kip Thorne's](http://www.pmaweb.caltech.edu/Courses/ph136/yr2012/1227.1.K.pdf) lecture series on Classical Mechanics. Section 27.6 of that Chapter covers, in great detail, how LIGO would actually work. In the idealized model, the gravitational waves (as seen in a local Lorentz frame of LIGO) change the length of the arms by an amount $\delta x=\frac12h_+\ell_x$ and $\delta_y=-\frac12h_+\ell_y$ where $h_+(t)$ is the gravitational wave (i.e., the increase in $x$ length is coincided by a decrease in the $y$ length of the same amount). The phase caused by this difference can be calculated to be
$$
\Delta\varphi(t)=\omega_0\,2\left(\delta x-\delta y\right)=\omega_0\left(\ell_x+\ell_y\right)h_+(t)
$$
where $\omega_0$ is the light's angular frequency (and $c=1$).

Since there is a phase shift, then the light intensity being sent to the photodetectors are *also* being modified, with the intensity linearly proportional to the phase shift, which leads it to being directly proportional to the gravitational wave:
$$
\Delta I_{PD}(t)\propto\Delta\varphi(t)=2\omega_0\ell h_+
$$
where we've assumed $\ell_x\approx\ell_y\equiv\ell$. There is a bit more detail involved in getting a *real* signal from a *real* set up (e.g., accounting for local gravity), but the basis for LIGO is essentially the above.

Note that the phase shift itself isn't caused by the lengthening and shortening of the paths because the wavelength of light *also* changes by this factor. Instead, it is measuring **the *arrival time* of the crests and troughs of the light wave between the two arms** (cf. [this LIGO Science Collaboration FAQ page](https://www.ligo.org/science/faq.php#mirror-distance) or [this Physics World article on the discovery](https://physicsworld.com/a/ligo-detects-first-ever-gravitational-waves-from-two-merging-black-holes/)), so it is more of a stopwatch than a ruler.

Thorne's notes also show the predicted signal LIGO should make,
[image]

which looks remarkably like the real signal
[image: real signal]
([source](https://www.businessinsider.com/gravitational-waves-signal-ligo-2016-2?international=true&r=US&IR=T))

Comment: I must be being a bit thick -  *why* is there a phase shift? Isn't the wavelength along the arms changed by exactly the same factor?

Comment: @RobJeffries: It's interferometer, so since the two beams aren't traveling the same length anymore, one is longer & the other shorter, there is an interference pattern, cf. the [LIGO science collaboration FAQ](http://www.ligo.org/science/GW-IFO.php).

Comment: Still not getting it. I know what an interferometer is. The phase of the wave at the detector $\phi_1 = mod(d_1/\lambda)$, where $d_1$ is the path length in arm 1, with a similar expression in arm 2. When you change the length of an interferometer arm you are keeping the wavelength constant - this results in a change in $\phi_1-\phi_2$. Why doesn't a gravitational wave change $d_1$ and $\lambda$ by the same factor resulting in no phase change. I'd be happy for an upvoter to set me straight... it obviously works!

Comment: @RobJeffries: Hmm, seems I'm explaining it wrong, as this is [answered at the aforementioned LSC](http://ligo.org/science/faq.php#mirror-distance): *the interference pattern doesn't come about because of the difference between the length of the arm and the wavelength of the light. Instead it's caused by the different arrival time of the light wave's "crests and troughs" from one arm with the arrival time of the light that traveled in the other arm.*

Comment: [Another page says this as well](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2016/feb/11/ligo-detects-first-ever-gravitational-waves-from-two-merging-black-holes), so it seems I'll have to update this, but I'm at work now, so it'll have to wait.

Comment: Is gravitational wave continuous event? Was aLIGO team just lucky that they turned the machine on just before the wave "hit" Earth? -> Is there a time window that we can "see" this grav. wave(s?) from this specific black holes merge or it's just a short event "blink of an eye" short?

Comment: @Kyslik: The gravitational wave is a "chirp," as you can see in the signal we received (2nd image). aLIGO was in some sense lucky, but the machine was *specifically designed* to observe GWs, so it's not much of a surprise that they found it. AFAIK, GWs are one-time events.

Comment: Thank you! So uppon merge (creation of one black hole) one big gravitational wave (spacetime distortion) was sent to surrounding including us and we captured it, correct? Is gravitational wave correct term to name it - Wouldn't it be better to call gravitational waves "spacetime distortion" instead?

Comment: @Kyslik: Yes, the wave we observed was produced at the point of the merger. Gravitational wave is the correct term because it is a [wave as physicists define it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave) and its origins is through gravity. I guess a spacetime distortion would be anything that distorts flat spacetime (i.e., gravity wells) and not just GWs.

Comment: In the response would be, in my opinion, appropriate to justify why, in the calculation of $ \Delta \varphi (t) $ is $ {\omega}_{0} $ assumed constant. Your answer, if I understand this, says that the square with the side equals to $x$, the gravitational wave changes to rectangle with $\delta$(the area changes from $x^2$ to $(x + \delta )(x - \delta)=x^2 - {\delta}^2$). Is that right? Next, I believe, that the energy density of this rectangle will be probably different. And this also cause a different frequency of light($E = {h}  {\nu}$). Or inflation or deflation will be occurred?

Comment: @StefanBabos: The light is monochromatic (i.e., single frequency), so $\omega_0$ should be a safe assumption. The phase difference is just the path-length difference of the two arms, no squaring involved (see Rob's answer as well).

Comment: You're probably right. Maybe something is leaking to me. I would like to clarify this? I have a monochrome source of light that will illuminate along the rod, which is long exactly one wavelength of this light. At the end of this rod will be always the same light intensity as its beginning. This will apply even if this rod I bring on the satellite GPS(for example) arbitrarily quickly? Or not?

Comment: @KyleKanos GWs are mostly transient phenomena from mergers and such, but there's also the proposed stochastic GW background, which would be ~continuous. I think this still comes from a multitude of ~instantaneous events all over the universe, but this is straining my very limited knowledge of the subject already.

Answer (score 12):

I have decided to add an answer to this because it is about the most commonly asked non-trivial question about the whole process that I have encountered. The paradox is that you can think about the detection in two ways. On the one hand you can imagine that the lengths of the detector arms change and that the round-trip travel time of a light beam is subsequently changed and so the difference in the time-of-arrival of wavecrests translates into a phase difference that is detected in the interferometer. On the other hand you have the analogy to the expansion of the universe - if the arm length is changed, then isn't the wavelength of the light changed by *exactly* the same factor and so there can be no change in the phase *difference*?

Clearly, the latter cannot be true. There is an excellent discussion of this by [Saulson 1997](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/65/6/10.1119/1.18578), from which I give a summary.

Interpretation 1:

If the two arms are in the $x$ and $y$ directions and the incoming wave the $z$ direction, then the metric due to the wave can be written
$$ds^2 = -c^2 dt^2 + (1+ h(t))dx^2 + (1-h(t))dy^2,$$
where $h(t)$ is the strain of the gravitational wave.

For light with $ds^2=0$ this means that (considering only the arm aligned along the x-axis for a moment)
$$c dt = \sqrt{(1 + h(t))}dx \simeq (1 + \frac{1}{2}h(t))dx$$
The time taken to travel the path is therefore
$$\tau_+ = \int dt = \frac{1}{c}\int (1 + \frac{1}{2}h(t))dx$$

If the original arm is of length $L$ and the perturbed arm length is $L(1+h)$, then the time difference for a photon to make the *round* trip along each arm is
$$ \Delta \tau = \tau_+ - \tau_- \simeq  \frac{2L}{c}h$$
leading to a phase difference in the signals of
$$\Delta \phi = \frac{4\pi L}{\lambda} h$$
**This assumes that $h(t)$ can be treated as a constant $h$ whilst the light is in the apparatus.**

Interpretation 2:

In analogy with the expansion of the universe, the gravitational wave *does* change the wavelength of light in each arm of the experiment. However, only the waves that are *in the apparatus* as the gravitational wave passes through can be affected.

Suppose that $h(t)$ is a step function so that the arm changes length from $L$ to $L+h(0)$ instantaneously. The waves that are just arriving back at the detector will be unaffected by this change, but subsequent wavecrests will have had successively further to travel and so there is a phase lag that builds up gradually to the value defined above in interpretation 1. The time taken for the phase lag to build up will be $2L/c$.

But then what about the waves that enter the apparatus later? For those, the laser *frequency* is unchanged and as the speed of light is constant, then the wavelength is unchanged. These waves travel in a lengthened arm and therefore experience a phase lag exactly equivalent to interpretation 1.

In practice, the "buildup time" for the phase lag is short compared with the reciprocal of the frequency of the gravitational waves. For example the LIGO path length is about 1000 km, so the "build up time" would be 0.003 s compared with the reciprocal of the $\sim 100$ Hz signal of 0.01 s and so is relatively unimportant when interpreting the signal. For higher frequency signals, there is indeed a reduction in the sensitivity of the instrument.

There is no paradox between the the two ways of thinking about this. So, you are correct that the wave changes both the lengths of the arms and the wavelength of light in the arms, but (obviously) incorrect that it prevents the instrument working.

Comment: 300 km ? is that right

Comment: @JoeBlow: I think it's actually longer. [This LIGO FAQ says](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/ligos-ifo) that the light is reflected 400 times each of the 4km arms before merging, so it's actually about *1600 km* long!

Comment: I asked (or re-asked) yet another angle on clarifying the .. ontology of the spacetime metric .. over here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235556/ligo-discovery-if-the-space-time-metric-is-changed-how-is-it-measured @RobJeffries

Comment: They aren't the same, though, are they? In 1., there is a constant phase difference between light of identical frequency from the arms. In 2., the frequencies of light from the arms differ.

Comment: They aren't 2 interpretations of the same events. They differ. 2. is correct, I think.

Comment: @innisfree no, the frequency of the laser is unchanged in both cases.

Comment: In your response(part 1), and also in the article to which you refer, is at the beginning stated the equation:
${ds}^{2} = - c^2  . t^2 + [1-h(t)]{dx}^{2} + [1+h(t)]{dy}^{2}$
From this relationship, it is seen that the dx and dy is influenced by h (t), but there is no stated or explained why the time t by h(t) is not affected. I believe that before stating this equation, it should be showed why time t is not affected by h(t). At what stage in creation of this relationship revealed that the time is not influenced by the h(t).

Comment: @StefanBabos I believe this is how $h$ is defined in the weak field limit of GR.

Comment: "the gravitational wave does change the wavelength of light in each arm of the experiment. " this doesn't happen in case 1.