# How can LIGO's measures be unequivocaly tied to gravitational waves?

Tags: experimental-physics, gravitational-waves, interferometry, ligo, noise

I understand that there are 2 devices so that the signal cannot have a local stimulation as a source. But why couldn't it be seismic activity for instance?

Given the accuracy of the devices couldn't it even be someone jumping on the ground between the two measurement stations?

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/236107/ and links therein. There are other questions on the site specifically related to seismic noise, I believe.

Comment: Seismic activity would not travel at the speed of light between 2 sites that are 3000 km apart. Also the devices are equipped with seismic sensors and other detectors. If the same signal was seen in seismic detector at LIGO at the same time, it would not be gravity wave.

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate. This question is asking whether the measurement could have been accounted to some other phenomenon (like seismic activity). The linked question is admitting that the measurement is indeed gravitational waves, but is asking if it is a merger of 2 black holes.